# Spark Executor is connection is getting closed

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

Hello I am reading the parquet file but I am getting below error in AWS EMR :-

ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 518 requests outstanding when connection from ip-100-73-112-181.ec2.internal/100.73.112.181:7337 is closed

My spark command :-

spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --class com.abcMain --driver-memory 6g --executor-memory 80g --conf avro.mapred.ignore.inputs.without.extension=false --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:ConcGCThreads=2 -XX:+UseCompressedOops" --conf spark.executor.cores=16 --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:ConcGCThreads=2 -XX:+UseCompressedOops" --conf spark.task.maxFailures=20 --conf spark.ui.retainedTasks=1280 --conf spark.yarn.am.attemptFailuresValidityInterval=1h --conf spark.yarn.executor.failuresValidityInterval=1h --conf spark.yarn.max.executor.failures=100 --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1

Comment: Usually the connection closed is result, not cause. Do you have any stdout/stderr logs, especially logs from the driver?